# Probability of a randomly chosen point in a right triangle being nearer to one side than to another.

Tags: probability

$\Delta$$ABC$ has angle $B=90°$ and angle $C=30°$. Find the probability that a randomly chosen point in $\Delta$$ABC$ is nearer to $AB$ than it is to $AC$.

This is a problem in a high school mathematics competition so the solution is probably quite simple, but I don't know where or how to start.

Comment: Can you **draw** the region where $P$ is closer to $AB$ than ro $AC$?

Comment: I did, but I'm pretty sure I did it wrong. I drew a line going from $A$ to the midpoint of $BC$. I assumed that if $P$ was on that line, it would be exactly between $AB$ and $AC$, so I got $\frac{1}{2}$ as the probability, which I don't think is correct.

Comment: As the other correspondents have noted, the locus of $P$ in the triangle equidistant from $AB$ and $AC$ is the angle bisector, not the median.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The locus of points $P$ such that $d(P,AB)=d(P,AC)$ is the angle bisector through $A$.
Assuming that $D\in BC$ is the foot of such angle bisector, you just need to compute the ratio $\frac{[ABD]}{[ABC]}$, that is simple through the bisector theorem or the sine theorem.

$\frac{[ABD]}{[ABC]}=\color{red}{\large\frac{1}{3}}$ is also pretty straightforward to notice by studying the following diagram:

[image]

Comment: I understood the OP is asking for a randomly chosen point "$\underline{inside}$" the $\Delta\mathrm{ABC}$. Isn't it ?.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Draw a bisector AD from vertex A to D on BC.  Find the area of $\triangle ABD$ and the ratio of triangle $\triangle ABD$ to the total area of $\triangle ABC$ is the required probability.